# ArcGIS Server - stopserver.sh vs. Admin Stop

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3

I'm curious to the underlying "cleaning" differences between restarting the entire ArcGIS Server process with stopserver.sh vs. doing a stop through the arcgis/admin console.

```
http://server:port/arcgis/admin/machines/<machine>/stop
```

Obviously stopserver.sh shuts down the entire process, and admin-stop will keep up the admin/rest APIs and Manager.

I've noticed that the above command shuts down all services and arcsoc.exe processes, but does it keep open states in the background that get resumed on startup, or would this be the equivalent of running stopserver.sh in regards to application server maintenance?

The problem that I am running into is that over time that ArcGIS Server does a poor job of recycling resources, eventually causing issues with services. I'd like to run a scheduled reboot, but currently have a clustered configuration and this would require running stopserver.sh separately on each system.

I would rather create something that is system-independent (In case I migrate), and that works through the web adapter.

Comment: ArcGIS Server already recycles services daily at midnight (or however frequently you have it configured). You can't "cold stop" AGS through the API (if you could, you certainly couldn't restart it, since it wouldn't be running to accept the request).  You could certainly script a restart request at the OS level, but it's not likely to be OS-agnostic.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS 10.3.1? I had some stability issues with 10.3 (on Lniux) until I upgraded to 10.3.1, then most of the issues went away.

Comment: @Vince Right. Not to mention if it's in a cluster I'd be worried about the first machine not rebooting, and then the entire system is down when the second machine restarts. I'd have to setup a network location between both machines to read a file on the other's result.

Comment: @Mintx 10.3. That's interesting, can you elaborate on what stability issues you had?

Comment: You can poll the REST API of server 2 to make sure it's up again before restarting server 1.  This could easily be done with Python, Java, or even a shell script with `curl`

Comment: @disflux Every 4 or 5 months, a random map service or two would stop responding. Clicking "Stop" in Server Manager would set the status to "Stopping..." and wouldn't change until I shut everything down. Occasionally, a java process would take off and consume 100% CPU for no reason until the server was rebooted.

Comment: @Mintx The service issues sound like what I have been experiencing, right around that same time frame. The java process jumping sounds like something we dealt with a while back with a corrupt data license. Did you ever test shutting down the machines through the admin API to see if that resolved the issue?